# WPF xctk TimePicker default value in XAML

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, timepicker

How can I set a default value for the WPF extended toolkit `TimePicker` in `XAML`? The `TimePicker` has no "`DefaultValue`" property like `DateTimePicker`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has no property like `DefaultValue`.

The `Value` property of `TimePicker`, which is a `DateTime`, if you want to set it in XAML, you can do it via data binding, first define a property (of type DateTime) in the view model, and give it a default value. And then bind the `Value` to this property.